# JAXB: Change name of XML Element from Java code?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

To set the name of an XML element I use annotations like this:

```
@XmlElement(name = "customer_id")
public String getId(){}
```

I have to communicate with two different webservices. One expacts an id element named `customer_id` but the other expacts the id element to be named `id`. I solved the problem by creating a second `Customer` class with the same attributes. The only different is that it uses the following annotation

```
@XmlElement(name = "id")
public String getId(){}
```

and it has a copy constructor which copies all attributes from `Customer1` to `Customer2`. When I am communicating with the first webservice I send a `Customer1` object and the other webservice gets a `Customer2` object.

Is there any possibility to use only one `Customer` object, but rename the `id` attribute to whatever the webservice expects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You can use the external mapping document extension in MOXy JAXB to apply a second mapping to your object model.  This mapping document can be be used to modify metadata provided via annotations, or completely replace it.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

**For a Detailed Example**

In the example below a single object model is mapped to the results of the Google and Yahoo weather APIs:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html